# RevTex 4.1 complaining about empty note when citing arXiv

Tags: bibtex

The RevTex 4.1 author's guide (http://www.physics.csbsju.edu/370/papers/Journal_Style_Manuals/auguide4-1.pdf, pg. 15) recommends using the following code to cite from the arXiv e-print repository:

```
@Unpublished{Ginsparg:1988ui,
author = "Ginsparg, Paul H.",
title = "{Applied Conformal Field Theory}",
year = "1988",
eprint = "hep-th/9108028",
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
SLACcitation = "%%CITATION=HEP-TH/9108028;%%"
}
```

But when I copy this code into my .bib file and compile it, I get "Warning--empty note in Ginsparg" because the required "note" field is empty.  Why does the documentation contain code that generates a warning?  How do I get rid of it?  I am using RevTex 4.1 and TexShop version 3.59.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the revtex template. The _note_ field is simply a mandatory field for _unpublished_ entries. Your options are to add something like "published on arxiv" to the note field or use another entry type like _misc_.

Comment: I find it very strange that the official RevTex documentation recommends code that generates a warning.